# Facebook SDK Graph API: create course object

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

I want to create a fitness.course object with OpenGraph API for later use in a fitness.runs action. When trying to create one using the code example from Facebook Open Graph reference page, I get following error: "HTTPStatusCode: 400, The parameter object is required". I can't figure out which parameter is meant, all required fields are set.

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"Sample Metrics: Speed: Value", @"fitness:metrics:speed:value",
                        @"Sample Course", @"og:title",
                        @"Sample Metrics: Custom-Unit Energy: Value", @"fitness:metrics:custom_unit_energy:value",
                        @"Sample Distance: Value", @"fitness:distance:value",
                        @"fitness.course", @"og:type",
                        @"Sample Speed: Units", @"fitness:speed:units",
                        @"Sample Metrics: Speed: Units", @"fitness:metrics:speed:units",
                        @"Sample Distance: Units", @"fitness:distance:units",
                        @"574731755910387", @"fb:app_id",
                        @"Sample Total Custom-Unit Energy: Value", @"fitness:custom_unit_energy:value",
                        @"Put your own URL to the object here", @"og:url",
                        @"Sample Metrics: Custom-Unit Energy: Units", @"fitness:metrics:custom_unit_energy:units",
                        @"Sample Metrics: Pace: Units", @"fitness:metrics:pace:units",
                        @"Sample Metrics: Distance: Units", @"fitness:metrics:distance:units",
                        @"Sample Splits: Values: Units", @"fitness:splits:values:units",
                        @"https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png", @"og:image",
                        @"Sample Pace: Units", @"fitness:pace:units",
                        @"Sample Metrics: Location: Latitude", @"fitness:metrics:location:latitude",
                        @"Sample Duration: Units", @"fitness:duration:units",
                        @"Sample Pace: Value", @"fitness:pace:value",
                        @"Sample Duration: Value", @"fitness:duration:value",
                        @"Sample Metrics: Pace: Value", @"fitness:metrics:pace:value",
                        @"Sample Speed: Value", @"fitness:speed:value",
                        @"Sample Splits: Values: Value", @"fitness:splits:values:value",
                        @"Sample Metrics: Location: Longitude", @"fitness:metrics:location:longitude",
                        @"Sample Total Custom-Unit Energy: Units", @"fitness:custom_unit_energy:units",
                        @"Sample Metrics: Distance: Value", @"fitness:metrics:distance:value",
                        nil
                        ];
/* make the API call */
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/objects/fitness.course"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                          if(error)
                          {
                              UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.description delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                              [alert show];
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Message successfully posted !" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                              [alert show];
                          }
                      }];
```